# Which parameters should I pass to form_set_value()?

Tags: 7, forms

I am trying to update a value during the validate phase of a node form: When the custom validation error is fired, I empty one of the fields.

I am trying to use the following code.

```php
function eventcheck_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {
  if ($node->type == 'article') {
    if ((array_key_exists('endpoints',$node->field_event_choose['und'][0])) && (($node->field_event_title['und'][0]['value']<>'') || (isset($node->field_event['und'][0]['value'])))) {
      $form_set_value(???);
      $form_set_error('event_checker_group',t('Error message'));
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that the last parameter for `form_set_value()` is the same `$form_state` the validation handler gets. What are the `$element` and the `$value`?

I was trying a lot and apparently the desired value resides in `$form['field_name']['und'][0]['value']['#value']` and only there. When I try `form_set_value($form['field_name']['und'][0]['value']['#value'],'foo',$form_state)`, I get this error.

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to drupal_array_set_nested_value() must be an array, string given, called in /includes/form.inc on line 2436 and defined in drupal_array_set_nested_value()

I also tried the following code.

```php
$newvalue = $form['field_name']['und'][0]['value'];
$newvalue['#value']='foo';
form_set_value($form['field_name']['und'][0]['value'],$newvalue,$form_state);
```

I get this error.

> Warning: mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in drupal_strlen()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, I finally managed to make this work. The trick lies inside `$form['complete form']`. but first things first, how does `form_set_value()` work and what does it do?

#### The `form_set_value()` function

As the documentation suggests:

> If you want to update the value of `$form['elem1']['elem2']`, which should be stored in `$form_state['values']['elem1']['elem2']`, you would set `$element['#parents'] = array('elem1','elem2')`.

Now what does that mean? In my case, I had a textfield called 'field_event_title', which is the name I gave it on creation. In `$form`, all fields have a sub-array in `$form['field_name']`, which in my case is `$form['field_event_title']`. This is where the submitted value also is stored. Since it is a textfield, Drupal maintains both the language and the delta [question for editors: is this right?] of the input data. So in fact, the value is not stored in `$form['field_name']['value']`, but in `$form['field_name']['und'][0]['value']` (`['und']=language; [0]=delta`). Note that "und" is the Drupal key for the default language of the site; if it is in German, then it would be "de"; however, in most cases it should be "und."

To actually change the value using `form_set_value()`, one is ought to invoke the function by writing:

```
form_set_value($form['field_name'], array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => 'foo'))), $form_state);
```

#### Updating a form to repopulate it with different values than submitted (or clearing them)

Thus far, this was what Krister Andersson suggested, but that did not work in my case, since I wanted to clear fields once a custom validation error has been invoked. One would suspect that the form repopulates itself using the values inside `$form_state['values']` (which is actually the place where the values are stored, the actual place that gets updated when using `form_set_value()` and the place which generates the `$form` later), but that is not the case: It uses the values inside `$form_state['complete form']`, which is a 'copy' of `$form` (notice that it is spelled 'complete form', with a space, not an underscore).

Using `$form_state['complete form']['field_name']['und'][0]['value']['#value'] = 'foo';` is what updates the values that actually repopulate the form on a validation error. (Note: you can, as do I in my usecase, set it to `=NULL` to simply empty the field.)

#### Summary

Where is the difference between `$form['field_name']` (e.g. updating through `form_set_value()`) and `$form['complete form']`? Well, the former updates the actual value, which then gets stored inside the database; the latter is being used to repopulate a form when it failed a validation.

Comment: Thank you Alex for a great write up! I've been trying to get this working for hours on an entity reference field.

Comment: Just a FYI, while a new value for a custom field that gets passed to form_set_value() might need to be placed in a specially constructed array, for a non-custom field like the node title, you need to set a placeholder value using `$form['title']['#value'] = NULL;` in the form_alter phase as [discussed in this comment on api.drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/comment/144#comment-144). If you don't you've continually get a "Title field is required" message.

Comment: I was able to set the value for a required Entity Reference field in the validation function by doing `form_set_value($form_state['complete form']['FIELD_NAME'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0], array('target_id' => $my_entity_id), $form_state);` This used the `['#parents']` value on this element to correctly store the entity ID in this field. It seems to be working for me, but is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working by doing this:

```
// hook_form_alter, check so it's the correct form and attach a validate function
function sample_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "sample_dummy_node_form") {
    $form['#submit']['#validate'] = 'sample_dummy_node_form_validate';
  }
}

// validate function, wich just sets the `title` field to `tjoohooo` using `form_set_value`
function sample_dummy_node_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['title']['#parents'] = array('title');
  form_set_value($form['title'],t('tjoohooo'), $form_state);
}
```

If you haven't done so already, you should have a look at the documentation [`form_set_value`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_value/7)

*** EDIT ***

In you example I guess the code in your validate method should be:

```
function hook_node_validate($node,$form,&$form_state) {
  if (fancy_stuff){
    $form['field_name']['#parents'] = array('field_name');
    form_set_value($form['field_name'],t('foo'),$form_state);
  } 
}
```

From the documentation for the parameters:

> $element: The form element that should have its value updated; in most
>   cases you can just pass in the element from the $form array, although
>   the only component that is actually used is '#parents'. If
>   constructing yourself, set $element['#parents'] to be an array giving
>   the path through the form array's keys to the element whose value you
>   want to update. For instance, if you want to update the value of
>   $form['elem1']['elem2'], which should be stored in
>   $form_state['values']['elem1']['elem2'], you would set
>   $element['#parents'] = array('elem1','elem2').

Comment: thanks for your reply, but either that still does not work, or I still have no clue. why should I declare $form['title']['#parents'] = array('title');? and in your case, it still angers about the new value being a string, not array. maybe I should have explained more in detail in what context i am calling form_set_value, please see for the edited part of my question. thanks!

Comment: I didn't mean that you should use `title` you should use `$form['your_field']['#parent'] = array('your_field')` where `your_field` is the name of the field whose value you would like to modify.

Comment: Also, it isn't the `form_set_value()` method that complains, but the `drupal_array_set_nested_value()` method wich is called from `form_set_value()` and the second parameter to that method is `$element['#parents']`.

Comment: thanks for your time krister! but now I have two new errors: `Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in _field_filter_items() - Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in text_field_validate()`

Comment: my main problem is still the meaning of "`For instance, if you want to update the value of $form['elem1']['elem2'], which should be stored in $form_state['values']['elem1']['elem2'], you would set $element['#parents'] = array('elem1','elem2').`" where would I set $element['#parents']? before the call? like so: `$element['#parents']=array('field_name' => ['und'] = > [0] = > ['value'] = > ['#value'] = > 'foo');`? and then? `form_set_value($form['field_name'],$element['#parents'],$form_state);`? I'm so sorry, but this is a mystery to me. :)

Comment: I think it would easier if you could edit your post and add a complete code example, then I could give you a version that works. Seems hard to explain.

Comment: okay, i updated my question. thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @Krister, no this way it does not work. Also #parents are already set in the $form I see. If it is a new variable then we'll need to set it's parents as the the api doc.