# Using form_set_value with commerce in custom form

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

I'm trying to change the value of a form within a custom Commerce Pane **during validation** but I get the following error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to drupal_array_set_nested_value() must be an array, string given, called in /var/www/vhosts/innovista.org/httpdocs/includes/form.inc on line 2514 and defined in drupal_array_set_nested_value() (line 6440 of /var/www/vhosts/innovista.org/httpdocs/includes/common.inc).

As far as I see my code is an array.

```
form_set_value($form_state['values'][$checkout_pane['pane_id']]['donation_amount'], array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => '999'))), $form_state);
```

I've been using `$checkout_pane['pane_id'] . '][donation_amount'` with `form_set_error()`, and it works fine. I can't understand why argument 2 is not working.

I have tried setting #parents as this question suggests:
[Using form_set_value() in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17839/using-form-set-value-in-drupal-7)

In the following way:

```
$form_state['values'][$checkout_pane['pane_id']]['donation_amount']['#parents'] = array( 'values',$checkout_pane['pane_id'], 'donation_amount');
```

But this produces an extra error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   donation_checkout_pane_pane_checkout_form_validate() (line 186 of
>   /var/www/vhosts/innovista.org/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/donation_checkout_pane/donation_checkout_pane.module).

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code executed from [form_set_value()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/form_set_value/7) is the following one.

```
function form_set_value($element, $value, &$form_state) {
  drupal_array_set_nested_value($form_state['values'], $element['#parents'], $value, TRUE);
}
```

`$checkout_pane['pane_id'] . '][donation_amount'` is a string, even if `$checkout_pane['pane_id']` is an array; this is because the string concatenation operator cast an array into a string.
If `$element` is a string, then `$element['#parents']` is a string made of one character, similarly to what happens with `$string[0]`, when `$string` is set to `'long string with many characters that are added just to make the string longer'`.

That explains the error about the second argument.

With [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7), `$checkout_pane['pane_id'] . '][donation_amount'` works because the function is expecting a string as first argument, and the format of that string is exactly the format of the string you are passing.

The first argument of [form_set_value()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_value/7) is a form API array for the form element for which you want to set the value. That is not the content of `$form_state['values']`. As that is the code for a form validation handler, it should be similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // …
  $form[$checkout_pane['pane_id']]['donation_amount']['#parents'] = array($checkout_pane['pane_id'], 'donation_amount');
  form_set_value($form[$checkout_pane['pane_id']]['donation_amount'], '999', $form_state);
}
```

You still need to verify the content of `$checkout_pane['pane_id']` is effectively the parent of the element you want to change. For that, you can install the Devel module, and print the structure of `$form` using `dpm($form);`.

As for the answer given in the other question, I can say it is based on the description present in [form_set_value()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_value/7) for the `$element` parameter.

> The form element that should have its value updated; in most cases you can just pass in the element from the $form array, although the only component that is actually used is '#parents'. If constructing yourself, set `$element['#parents']` to be an array giving the path through the form array's keys to the element whose value you want to update. For instance, if you want to update the value of `$form['elem1']['elem2']`, which should be stored in `$form_state['values']['elem1']['elem2']`, you would set `$element['#parents'] = array('elem1','elem2');`.

Comment: hey @kiamlaluno, I am getting the same error when I use `form_set_value($form_state['values'][$checkout_pane['pane_id']]['donation_amount'], '23', $form_state);` Any ideas?

Comment: I've checked that I'm targeting the array correctly by doing ` drupal_set_message($form_state['values'][$checkout_pane['pane_id']]['donation_amount']);` and it successfully shows the original value. But still has this error when using it in form_set_value`()`

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm calling this function during form validation. Another person has the same issue here:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17839/using-form-set-value-in-drupal-7

No resolution for using form_set_value() to change the value though :S

Comment: The solution is setting `$element['#parents']`, for what I can understand.

Comment: I have updated the question, when setting #parents it produces another error...which suggest Drupal is turning my array into a string...any thoughts?

Comment: `$form_state['values'][$checkout_pane['pane_id']]['donation_amount']['#parents']` is probably the wrong value because the form structure gets flattened, if the form doesn't set #tree to `TRUE`.

Comment: I seemed to have found a solution: `form_set_value($form[$checkout_pane['pane_id']]['donation_amount'], '999', $form_state);`. Switching $form_status['values'] with $form. Do you see any issues with this?

Comment: That is correct. I am not sure #parents needs to be set, as the form element is part of a form, and #parents should be already set. If you are getting an error when you don't set #parents, my answer shows how to set it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this. It worked without setting #parents :)