# How to use form_set_value for a select list field?

Tags: forms

Drupal 7. in my validate form function, I use [form_set_value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_value/7) to set the value for the field "statut_metier" to 'draft'

If my field is a text field, this code works :

```
form_set_value($form['field_statut_metier'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'], 'draft', $form_state);
```

If my field is a list(text) field, with the key for the value 'draft' = 5

I can't manage to have the form_set_value function work.

Using [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and dpm() I have search to reach this field value :

I have tried :

```
form_set_value($form['field_statut_metier2'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#value'][0], '5' , $form_state);
```

but it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Comment: See if [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/18196/8623) answer helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I read this post but it doesn't seem to be related to select list fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php form_set_value($form['field_statut_metier2'][LANGUAGE_NONE], array(0 => array('value' => 2)), $form_state); ?>
```

From the [form_set_value()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_value/7) documentation on the first argument:

> you can just pass in the element from the $form array, although the only component that is actually used is '#parents'

Alternatively you can do:

```
<?php $form_state['values']['field_statut_metier2'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = '2'; ?>
```

... which is what form_set_value() does anyways.

Comment: Thanks, it works great, using this code :

`form_set_value($form['field_statut_metier'][LANGUAGE_NONE], array(0 => array('value' => 5)), $form_state);
`
 I don't know why the field value is an array (it's not a multi value field), but know I know how to use this function when the value is an array.